# Updating Custom Claims jar file for API Manager 2.0 and IDS 5.2

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to update the imports in our custom claims java files. So far what I have found was nothing much had changed but one import really. The org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.**impl**.token.URLSafeJWTGenerator changed to org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.**keymgt**.token.URLSafeJWTGenerator. When I add this change to the file it says the populateCustomClaims method no longer works.

### JAVA CODE

```
import edu.wso2.is.helper.DomainEntity;
import edu.wso2.is.helper.DomainEntityHelper;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dto.APIKeyValidationInfoDTO;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.URLSafeJWTGenerator;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.*;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class CustomTokenGenerator extends URLSafeJWTGenerator {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomTokenGenerator.class);

static String DOMAIN_DIALECT = "http://domain.edu/claims";
private final DOMAINEntityHelper DOMAINEntityHelper = new DOMAINEntityHelper();

public CustomTokenGenerator() {
}



//there is no access to the api call headers, etc. only what was passed in the DTO

public Map<String, String> populateCustomClaims(APIKeyValidationInfoDTO keyValidationInfoDTO, String apiContext, String version, String accessToken)
        throws APIManagementException {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("populateCustomClaims starting");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();//map for custom claims
    Map<String, String> claims = super.populateCustomClaims(keyValidationInfoDTO,apiContext,version,accessToken);

    boolean isApplicationToken =
            keyValidationInfoDTO.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase(APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_USER_TYPE_APPLICATION) ? true : false;
    if (isApplicationToken) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("Application Token detected - no resource owner claims will be added");
    }
    else {
        String netid = extractNetId(keyValidationInfoDTO.getEndUserName());

        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("adding resource owner claims to map - netid " + netid);

        map = addResourceOwnerClaims(netid, map);
    }

    String consumerKey = keyValidationInfoDTO.getConsumerKey();
    String dialect = getDialectURI();
    String subscriberNetId = extractNetId(keyValidationInfoDTO.getSubscriber());

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("adding client claims to map - subscriberNetId " + subscriberNetId + " client_id " + consumerKey);

    map.put(dialect + "/client_id",consumerKey);

    map = addClientClaims(consumerKey, subscriberNetId, map);

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("populateCustomClaims ending");

    return map;
}

private Map<String, String> addClientClaims(String consumerKey, String subscriberNetId, Map<String, String> map) {

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("addClientClaims starting");

    if (consumerKey == null) {
        return map;
    }
    boolean isConsumerClaims = true;
    DOMAINEntity identifiers = DOMAINEntityHelper.getDOMAINEntityFromConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    if (identifiers == null) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("No claims found for consumerKey, using subscriberNetId");
        isConsumerClaims = false;
        identifiers = DOMAINEntityHelper.getDOMAINEntityFromNetId(subscriberNetId);
        if (identifiers == null)
            return map;
    }
    if (isConsumerClaims)
        map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/client_claim_source", "CLIENT_ID");
    else
        map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/client_claim_source", "CLIENT_SUBSCRIBER");

    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/client_subscriber_net_id", subscriberNetId);
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/client_person_id", identifiers.getPersonId());
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/client_net_id", identifiers.getNetId());
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/client_surname", identifiers.getSurname());

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("addClientClaims ending");
    return map;
}
/* adds resource owner credentials to the map */
private Map<String, String> addResourceOwnerClaims(String netid, Map<String, String> map) {

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("addResourceOwnerClaims starting");

    if (netid == null) {
        return map;
    }
    DOMAINEntity identifiers = DOMAINEntityHelper.getDOMAINEntityFromNetId(netid);
    if (identifiers == null) {
        return map;
    }
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/resourceowner_person_id", identifiers.getPersonId());
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/resourceowner_domain_id", identifiers.getDomainId());
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/resourceowner_surname", identifiers.getSurname());
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/resourceowner_rest_of_name", identifiers.getRestOfName());
    map.put(DOMAIN_DIALECT + "/resourceowner_surname_position", identifiers.getSurnamePosition());

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("addResourceOwnerClaims ending");
    return map;
}

private String extractNetId(String carbonIdentifier) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("extractNetId starting");
        log.debug("step 1: carbonIdentifier is " + carbonIdentifier);
    }
    String netid = UserCoreUtil.removeDomainFromName(carbonIdentifier);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("step 2: after remove domain netid is " + netid);
    if (netid != null) {
        if (netid.endsWith("@carbon.super")) {
            netid = netid.replace("@carbon.super", "");
        }
    }
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("extractNetId ending with result " + netid);
    return netid;
  }
}
```

I also updated the pom.xml dependency

### XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>edu.wso2.is</groupId>
<artifactId>edu.wso2.is.CustomClaimsGenerator</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Custom Claims Generator</name>
<repositories>
    <repository>
         <releases>
           <enabled>true</enabled>
           <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
           <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
         </releases>
         <id>wso2-nexus</id>
         <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
       </repository>

</repositories>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec.wso2</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0.wso2v1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help or point in some direction would be much appreciated. 
THANK YOU!

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer works"?

Comment: This code was written for IDS 5.1 and API 1.10.0 so with all the library changes, it no longer works so I'm trying to update imports and the likes to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`populateCustomClaims()` signature is changed like this in APIM 2.0.0. Now it takes a [`TokenValidationContext` object](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/service/TokenValidationContext.java).

```
public Map<String, String> populateCustomClaims(TokenValidationContext validationContext)  
    throws APIManagementException {
```

The code is [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/token/JWTGenerator.java#L83).

Comment: Thanks for the help! That got me one step closer to updating the code. But now I get an error with the **keyValidationInfoDTO**. I have no idea what to change it too, or if I'm not importing something right, because it should be part of the code. Any ideas?

Comment: The error says keyValidationInfoDTO cannont be resolved. I tired putting validationContext in place of it, but then it throws the error the method getUserType() is undefined for the type TokenValidationContext. I'm not sure what  keyValidationInfoDTO even does though anyways. Thank you

Comment: are you talking about `keyValidationInfoDTO` object or `APIKeyValidationInfoDTO` class?

Comment: The keyValidationInfoDTO object. I get an error with any instance of keyValidationInfoDTO for example `keyValidationInfoDTO.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase(APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_USER_TYPE_APPLICATION) ? true : false;` I tried two different things with it: Making two different variable - `private APIKeyValidationInfoDTO key = new APIKeyValidationInfoDTO();` and `APIKeyValidationInfoDTO key = validationContext.getValidationInfoDTO();` They both got rid of the errors but my custom claims still wont work.

Comment: `validationContext.getValidationInfoDTO()` should work.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I finally got it working today. I really appreciate it. You're a legend.